# What is a meaning of 一口 in 他会说一口标准的英语?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 他会说一口标准的英语
>
> He can speak standard English.

So I think that 一口 can be omitted and still the sentence can make sense.

How actually 一口 work in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

口 is a classifier for some nouns that are related to the mouth, for example, speech, taste, and bite

Example:

北京腔 = Beijing accent --> 一口北京腔  = A mouthful of (a full language of) Beijing accent

大蒜味 = garlic taste/ smell --> 滿口大蒜味 = A mouthful of garlic taste/smell

吃鱼肉 = eat fish meat --> 吃几口鱼肉 = Eat a few bites of fish meat

- 他会说标准的英语 = he can speak standard English
- 他会说(一口)标准的英语 = he can speak a mouthful of (a full language of) standard English

If we change the classifier from 口 to 句 and write "他会说(一句)标准的英语", it would mean "he can speak (a sentence of) standard English" -- We don't know if he has a full vocabulary or not

Answer (score -1):

He speaks fluent English. (他說一口流利的英語)